# How to use CASE WHEN function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, case-when

I am trying to solve this problem and I am not sure if using `CASE WHEN` is the right solution.

I am trying to manipulate the data. If product equals `A` then price has to be 100, not the price from the table and I am not sure how to achieve that.

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
(
     Product VARCHAR(250), 
     subproduct VARCHAR(250), 
     Orderdate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO TEST (product, subproduct, orderdate)  
VALUES ('A', 'blue',  '2019/01/01'), 
       ('B', 'orange','2019/01/11'),  
       ('C', 'lemon', '2019/01/15'),  
       ('D', 'lemon', '2019/01/20'),
       ('A', 'blue',  '2019/12/31'), 
       ('B', 'orange','2019/12/31'),  
       ('C', 'lemon', '2019/12/15'),  
       ('D', 'lemon', '2019/12/31');
```

```
CREATE TABLE PriceTest 
(
     Product VARCHAR(250), 
     Price NUMERIC(10,2), 
     Pricedate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO PriceTest (product, price, pricedate)  
VALUES ('A', 10.00,'2019/12/31'), 
       ('B', 50.00,'2019/12/31'),  
       ('C', 30.00,'2019/12/31'),  
       ('D', 50.00,'2019/12/31'),
       ('A', 20.00,'2019/10/31'), 
       ('B', 40.00,'2019/10/31'),  
       ('C', 50.00,'2019/10/31'),  
       ('D', 10.00,'2019/11/30');
```

Select query:

```
SELECT
    t.product, t.subproduct, p.price, p.pricedate 
FROM
    test t
JOIN
    pricetest p ON p.product = t.product 
WHERE 
    p.pricedate = '12/31/2019' 
ORDER BY
    t.product
```

Current results:

```
   product  subproduct  price   pricedate
   ---------------------------------------
    A       blue        10      12/31/2019
    A       blue        10      12/31/2019
    B       orange      50      12/31/2019
    B       orange      50      12/31/2019
    C       lemon       30      12/31/2019
    C       lemon       30      12/31/2019
    D       lemon       50      12/31/2019
    D       lemon       50      12/31/2019
```

Desired result: whenever the product = A, Price should be = 100 otherwise price stays the same from pricetest table for others.

```
   product  subproduct  price   pricedate
   ---------------------------------------
     A      blue        100     12/31/2019
     A      blue        100     12/31/2019
     B      orange      50      12/31/2019
     B      orange      50      12/31/2019
     C      lemon       30      12/31/2019
     C      lemon       30      12/31/2019
     D      lemon       50      12/31/2019
     D      lemon       50      12/31/2019
```

Comment: Think about your schema. If you are only concerned with dates, then use the date datatype, not datetime. Do not encourage the use of a precision that is greater than what you design/code for.

Comment: Thank you for editing my questions and code. i appreciate it! I will follow the format you corrected me by.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `CASE` to do it:

```
select 
    t.product
    ,t.subproduct
    ,CASE WHEN t.product = 'A' 
        THEN 100
        ELSE p.price
    END AS price
    ,p.pricedate 
from 
    test t
    join pricetest p on p.product = t.product 
where 
    p.pricedate = '20191231' 
order by t.product
```

By the way, you really should be using the following format for date literals in SQL Server: `YYYYMMDD`.

Don't write

```
pricedate = '12/31/2019'
```

Write

```
pricedate = '20191231'
```

See [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have one more question why when I filter to 100, it doesn't show me any results.

 SELECT 
    t.product
   ,t.subproduct
   ,CASE WHEN t.product = 'A' 
         THEN 100
        ELSE p.price
 END AS price
    ,p.pricedate  from test t
 JOIN pricetest p on p.product = t.product 
 WHERE 
    p.pricedate = '20191231' and p.price = 50
 ORDER BY t.product
When I run this code it doesn't show any data where value is 100. How can I have it to give me rows where price is 100 regardless if it in the price table or case when is used. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry @zofia, it is hard for me to explain the basics of SQL here. I feel like there is too much to explain. You need to understand in general what the `WHERE` part of the query does. I can only recommend you to read some book on database querying, relational algebra in general and SQL in particular.

Comment: @zofia, yes, `WHERE` is filtering on actual values that equal to 50 in the `price` table. If you want to keep rows that have `product = 'A'` as well, you can write `WHERE (price=50 OR product = 'A')`